# Uniform Convergence in Cramer's Theorem (Large Deviations)

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $ X_1, X_2, \dots $ be a sequence of iid real random variables with finite logarithmic moment generating function $\Lambda$. Cramer's theorem says that, for $x > \operatorname E[X_1].$,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \log P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = nx \right) = -\Lambda^*(x)$$
where $\Lambda^*$ is the Legendre transform of $\Lambda$.

Under which conditions does the limit hold uniformly in $x \in (a, b)$?

My end goal would be to prove the following:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \chi_n(x) = -\partial_x\Lambda^*(x)$$
where $\chi_n(x) = \partial_x \log P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = x)$.

Comment: See "A unified formulation of the central limit theorem for small and large deviations from the mean",  Thomas Höglund ,
_Zeitschrift für Wahrscheinlichkeitstheorie und Verwandte Gebiete_ volume 49, pp. 105–117(1979)  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00534343

Comment: @kimchilover My university's library doesn't seem to have online access to this article. I am curious though, what is the "punchline" of this result? Is it some kind of "matching" between the usual CLT result and the usual Cramer's theorem result? Is there some nontrivial result in the intermediate regime?

Comment: It's technical.  It covers all of the above, with $\lambda$ function, uniformity over $x$ in compact sets, keeping track of things $(1+O(1/n))$ factors. A more complicated but JSTOR-accessible  follow on paper is "On Approximating Probabilities for Small and Large Deviations in Rd",  J. Robinson, T. Hoglund, L. Holst and M. P. Quine _The Annals of Probability_ Vol. 18, No. 2 (Apr., 1990), pp. 727-753 (27 pages)/